# Is it possible to avoid ANR using StrictMode in android?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, android-strictmode

Somewhere I read that By using StrictMode we can avoid ANR in android. I tried like that below is the code

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {


        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .penaltyFlashScreen()
                .penaltyDeath()
                .detectDiskReads()
                .detectDiskWrites()
                .detectNetwork()
                .build());

    super.onCreate();
}
```

and i tried to generate ANR for the testing purposes like below:

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("kishan","onTouchEvent");
    while(true) {}
}
```

But still, ANR is coming on the screen. how to avoid ANR by using StrictMode? is it possible?

Comment: [StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) can give you some info (" `StrictMode` is a developer tool which detects things you might be doing by accident and brings them to your attention so you can fix them."). But if your doing too much work on the UI thread (the usual cause of ANR), then you need to use background threads/AsyncTasks to take the strain. See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: @JonGoodwin oh u mean it will not dismiss ANR

Comment: No such luck, it only warns you if it spots something you might want to look at, **YOU** have to fix the problems !

Comment: @JonGoodwin Ok..Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**What is ANR?**

When the UI thread of an Android app is blocked for too long, an "Application Not Responding" (ANR) error is triggered. If the app is in the foreground, Android will display the ANR dialog for a particular application when it detects one of the following conditions:

- No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch events) within **5 seconds.**
- A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within **10 seconds.**

**How to avoid ANR?**

By keeping your application's main thread responsive, you can prevent ANR dialogs from being shown to users.

- In particular, **activities should do as little as possible to set up
  in key life-cycle methods** such as `onCreate()` and `onResume()`.
- Potentially **long running operations** such as network or database
  operations, or computationally expensive calculations such as
  resizing bitmaps **should be done in a worker thread** like
  [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

**Diagnosing ANRs:**

- The app is doing slow operations involving I/O on the main thread.
- The app is doing a long calculation on the main thread.
- The main thread is doing a synchronous binder call to another process, and that other process is taking a long time to return.
- The main thread is blocked waiting for a synchronized block for a long operation that is happening on another thread.
- The main thread is in a deadlock with another thread, either in your process or via a binder call.

[StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) is a developer tool which detects accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread, where UI operations are received and animations take place. You can use StrictMode at the application or activity level.

Checkout official android developer documents to know, [How to fix the ANR problems?](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr.html#fix_the_problems)

Answer (score 1):

As the [StrictMode documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) says:

> StrictMode is a developer tool which detects things you might be doing
>   by accident and brings them to your attention so you can fix them.

StrictMode will help you telling which part of your code doing some excessive works like network or disk by limiting the access then giving you ANR or a crash log which depends by the penalty you've set. It won't remove any of your ANR but limit you from creating code which result in ANR.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Strict Mode by the following code snippet

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

What you were doing is enabling strict mode, you need to disable it, as per I understand your question.